# Not-quite-opposite of "inherit", someone from whom you inherit without their mentioning you in a will

Tags: antonyms

What is the verb for being the non-volitional source of an inheritance? For example:

> I "inherit" a car from my parent when they die. My parent "_____" a car to me when they die.

What is the "____"? I thought about "bequeaths" but that refers to specifically mentioning someone in a will, rather than passively being the source of the inheritance.

Relatedly, what is the term for the relationship between these two words? These words aren't antonyms, it's more like immigrate vs emigrate.

Comment: I am not clear on why "bequeath" does not work there...

Comment: ***Bequeath:*** verb (used with object)
to dispose of (personal property, especially money) by last will:
*She bequeathed her half of the company to her niece.*

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for inheriting something without a will, but by law.

Comment: @Mitch yes "inverse" is what I was looking for.

Comment: @user121863 I think "left" is closer than "bequeathed", but both of those are active. Does a verb exist that means "to passively be the source of an inheritance"?

Comment: I'm sure that 'left' is closer than 'bequeathed', which makes me wonder why the wrong answer was accepted. 'X left Y a, b and c' neither demands nor prohibits volition on the part of X. But 'leaver' as an agent noun doesn't work here.  'Unwitting benefactor' is the closest I've got.

Comment: @Jonathan If you're looking for a passive source, then literally use the passive voice: "The inheritance __was bequeathed by_ the benefactor."

Comment: If you get something from a dead person without them explicitly mentioning it in their will, e.g. because it's the law that you get it (in some countries children get shares in a parent's estate whether there is a will or not) then you could say it _passed_ to you, and there is no verb for the parent's action, because there was no action.

Comment: Thanks MichaelHarvey and Mitch for 2 good examples of how to use the passive voice.

Comment: I have attempted to sanitize the question, which originally disagreed with the usage of bequeath

Comment: Also, I would suggest: progenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you mentioned

> [bequeath](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bequeath)

is the correct verb for giving things in a will (after you die). The person who does the giving is called a

> [benefactor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benefactor)

(though that works for people who are still alive). The thing that is given is a

> [bequest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bequest)

Putting it all together:

> The benefactor bequeathed a bequest to the inheritor (or heir or recipient).

This is fairly formal. The way to say it normally is (after commenter user121863) is:

> They **left** me an inheritance.

As to what to call the relationship between the two verbs 'inherit' and 'bequeath' they are not antonyms (they don't appear in thesauruses as such). They are called

> inverses

of each other. An antonym or opposite of X is something that is -not- X, but for relations that are naming the same action but go in the opposite direction, one is the inverse of the other.

'Emigrate' and 'immigrate' aren't inverses but are obviously on the opposite sides of -something-. It's all about where the speaker is in relation to the person who moved countries. Someone emigrates from here to there, but they immigrate to here from there. Some kind of inverse relation could be extracted from these, but on the surface the words are not antonyms or inverses.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bequeath) mandates that the benefactor _arranges_ for the legacy to be in line with their wishes.

Comment: While I may be wrong on both these assertions; I think this is both the closest to correct that English has available, and yet still falls short of conveying the inverted relation to "inherit". I've proposed an edit to the question illustrating why, but the short version is that biological traits are inherited, such as eye color. Similarly CSS rules are inherited, and many other trades use the word inherited in such a fashion to mean some quality is given to a progeny tier of an ancestral tier in any kind of hierarchy. Thus "inherit" is not tied to death as bequeath is, nor always voluntary